# What would be the most efficient use of e-mail addresses for ecommerce

Tags: email, ecommerce, customer-service

I am not sure if this is exactly the right section. What do you find the most efficient, clear and reachable use of e-mail addresses to use for the customer?

I thought a standard 'sales, 'support' might work but it might look a little samey. Do users respond well when e-mails are replied by staff with named e-mail addresses such as susan@domain.com  or a generic one?

I am currently developing a small scale ecommerce website to gain some hands on insight into web retail. Any additional advice would be brilliant.

Comment: Welcome to webmasters. This is off-topic for this site. You could try http://answers.onstartups.com/.

Answer (score 0):

IMO it's useless to have emails by persons names for general queries for that field and it would make some problems too...

Make one id for each section, such as sales, support... and ofc your employees should sign their emails with their own name!

But sometimes, the employees might also need a personal email id, let say a sales representative has to engage with a costumer personally... although you can help it by assigning each email with a unique ID too...

Well, these all can be different if you only have one employee for each section, then a personal email may be more trustworthy for the costumers...